# Cordova on Android 4.4 CSS and Javascript compatibility

Tags: android, cordova, webview, compatibility

I'm developing a cordova app, testing on Android 7 and 6 everything works.
When I try to install the app on an Android 4.4 device it starts, but the CSS is rendered very bad (missing borders and other ugly stuff) and some Javascript functions are not supported (e.g. Array.forEach).
I think because the webview on Android 4.4 is old but I don't know how to solve this.
I tried to install Crosswalk but it does nothing, it doesn't appear in navigator.userAgent so I think it doesn't work.
I have this in my plugin list:

```
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.3.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
```

And this in my navigator.userAgent

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; Android SDK built for x86 Build/KK) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Have you tried to log the warnings and errors appearing in the WebView console?

Comment: It just show Javascript errors because of new features I used not supported, but I can find workarounds for that.
It says nothing about css but it's the biggest problem :/

Comment: You should identify the missing functionalities and then you need to add the necessary JS polyfill to your page. Like [this one for Array.forEach](https://gist.github.com/janbaer/5660471)

Comment: I'm fixing the javascript problems but the CSS still looks so bad.
I was hoping in something to support newer functionalities in old webview but I can't find anything.
The CSS is so messed up I will spend a lot of time for fixing everything manually. And the css is not complex and modern stuff, I don't know why it's not supported.

Comment: [cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) for Android 4.x

Comment: I tried to install Crosswalk but it does nothing, it doesn't appear in navigator.userAgent so I think it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.
Crosswalk was the solution but I failed at installing it because you need to build from cordova and not from Android Studio.
I was building from android studio because cordova gave me an error with gradle version.
I fixed the build from cordova, reinstalled crosswalk and now I can use it without problems and it supports all the new functionalities.